# Python Dividing A series data into groups for constructing box plots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, seaborn

My data frame column has values and I want to divide this into two groups <100, 100-1000, and construct the box plot.

My code:

```
df=
     value
0    10
1    30
2    60
3    90
4    30
5    350
6    670
7    230
8    80
9    900
10   200
11   840

# I want  to divide this into two groups <100, 100-1000 and draw boxplot for each group.

df['<100'] =  df['value'].le(100)
df['100-1000'] =  df['value'].gt(100)
df['group'] = df[['<100','100-1000']].eq(True).idxmax()
grpbox = df.groupby('group')['value'].agg(lambda x:list(x))
#boxplot
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(x="group", y="value", data=dcacgrp)
plt.show()
```

Present output:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'group'
```

Is there a better approach than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [10, 30, 60, 90, 100, 30, 350, 670, 230, 80, 900, 200, 840]
})

df['group'] = pd.cut(df['value'],
                     bins=[0, 100, 1000],
                     labels=['<100','100-1000'],
                     right=False)

sns.boxplot(x="group", y="value", data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Excellent answer. Just one line. Mine went to five lines with no solution. You are fabulous. Thanks a ton. I did not know about `pd.cut`.